# Mocking not working for Socket class

Tags: java, easymock

I want to return a defined Socket instance whenever new Socket("server ip", portNum) is called,
my code looks like this (am using easymock)

```
public static  Socket  mockSocket ;
public static  Object []arguments = {"Test Client",8443};
...........................................
..............................................

mockSocket = new Socket("20.206.214.76", 8080);

PowerMock.createMock(Socket.class, arguments);      

expectNew(Socket.class,arguments).andReturn(mockSocket);
```

its giving me compilation  error on ->

```
PowerMock.createMock(Socket.class, arguments);
```

error is:

```
"The type org.easymock.ConstructorArgs cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files"
```

Can someone pls help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the necessary EasyMock jars in your classpath. The compiler is looking for the class org.easymock.ConstructorArgs and cannot find it.

Once you have got the right jars in your classpath, however, you need to work on your general understanding of Java and mocking.

```
 // here you create a *real* Socket and assign it to 'mockSocket'
 mockSocket = new Socket("20.206.214.76", 8080);

 // here you create a mock Socket, but don't assign it to anything
 // 'arguments' probably doesn't do what you expect.
 PowerMock.createMock(Socket.class, arguments); 

 // here you tell your test case to intercept calls to `new Socket()` and
 // return mockSocket (which, as we see above) is a real socket.
 expectNew(Socket.class,arguments).andReturn(mockSocket);
```

What you actually need to do is *not* create a real socket. Assign the mock socket you create to `mockSocket`, and use that in your expectNew. Your test class needs to be annotated with `@PrepareForTest`, or `expectNew()` won't work.

```
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
 @PrepareForTest( MyClass.class )
 public class MyClassTest {
     // ... 
     @Test
     public void testSocket() {
         // create mock object
         Socket mockSocket = PowerMock.createMock(Socket.class);
         // tell test runner to intercept 'new Socket()'
         expectNew(Socket.class,arguments).andReturn(mockSocket); 

         MyClass objectUnderTest = new MyClass();
         // do things to objectUnderTest
         // because of @PrepareForTest and expectNew(), when MyClass
         //    hits 'new Socket(...)' the mock will be returned instead.
         // assert things about objectUnderTest
     }
 }
```

Comment: Am using TestNG , its giving me error in when i put unWith(PowerMockRunner.class)

Comment: Never say "it is giving me an error". Always say what the error actually is. I'm guessing it's another class-not-found error due to missing JARs.

Comment: My understnding is @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) works only with JUNIT, need to know if it works with TESTNG as well?